# Creating an object which has multiple level of children. Saves properly with one level, but not multiple levels

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I have a User class which has a one-to-many relationship with a PlaylistCollection class.
Similarly, the PlaylistCollection has a one-to-many relationship with the Playlist class.

I want to create a new User object and save it to the database. As a side-effect, I expect a new PlaylistCollection and a new Playlist to be written to the database, too. When I call commit -- NHibernate throws an exception:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [Playlists] (CollectionId, Title, Position, Id) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3)',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier,@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 int,@p3 uniqueidentifier',@p0='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',@p1=N'New Playlist',@p2=0,@p3='CD593D78-5300-434E-B256-6271D4A60915'

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK66D0C3A319AEA85C". The conflict occurred in database "StreamusTest", table "dbo.PlaylistCollections", column 'Id'.
```

This error does not occur if I omit giving my PlaylistCollection an initial Playlist object. I am able to write a User with a PlaylistCollection to the database fine, but not a User -> PlaylistCollection -> Playlist.

My mappings:

```
  <class name="User" table="[Users]" lazy="false">
    <id name="Id" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name" />

    <bag name="PlaylistCollections" cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
      <key column="UserId" />
      <one-to-many class="PlaylistCollection" />
    </bag>
  </class>

  <class name="PlaylistCollection" table="[PlaylistCollections]" lazy="false" >
    <id name="Id" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>

    <property name="Title" not-null="true" />

    <bag name="Playlists" cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
      <key column="CollectionId" />
      <one-to-many class="Playlist" />
    </bag>
  </class>

  <class name="Playlist" table="[Playlists]" lazy="false" >
    <id name="Id" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>

    <property name="CollectionId" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Title" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Position" not-null="true" />

    <bag name="Items" cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
      <key column="PlaylistId" />
      <one-to-many class="PlaylistItem" />
    </bag>
  </class>
```

and the entities constructors / helper methods:

```
public User()
{
    Name = string.Empty;
    PlaylistCollections = new List<PlaylistCollection>
        {
            new PlaylistCollection("New Playlist Collection")
        };
}

public PlaylistCollection()
{
    Id = Guid.Empty;
    UserId = Guid.Empty;
    Title = string.Empty;
    Playlists = new List<Playlist>();

    //  A collection should always have at least one Playlist.
    CreatePlaylist();
}

public PlaylistCollection(string title) 
    : this()
{
    Title = title;
}


public Playlist()
{
    Id = Guid.Empty;
    CollectionId = Guid.Empty;
    Title = string.Empty;
    Position = -1;
    Items = new List<PlaylistItem>();
}
public Playlist CreatePlaylist()
{
    string playlistTitle = string.Format("New Playlist {0:D4}", Playlists.Count);
    var playlist = new Playlist(playlistTitle);
    return AddPlaylist(playlist);
}

public Playlist AddPlaylist(Playlist playlist)
{
    if (Id != Guid.Empty)
    {
        playlist.CollectionId = Id;
    }

    playlist.Position = Playlists.Count;

    Playlists.Add(playlist);
    return playlist;
}
```

and finally, here's the method that fails:

```
/// <summary>
///     Creates a new User and saves it to the DB. As a side effect, also creates a new, empty
///     PlaylistCollection (which has a new, empty Playlist) for the created User and saves it to the DB.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The created user with a generated GUID</returns>
public User CreateUser()
{
    User user;
    try
    {
        NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.BeginTransaction();

        user = new User();
        user.ValidateAndThrow();
        UserDao.Save(user);

        NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.CommitTransaction();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Logger.Error(exception);
        NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.RollbackTransaction();
        throw;
    }

    return user;
}
```

Obviously the issue is that the Playlist object is trying to save itself with a CollectionId of Guid.Empty. It should be trying to save itself with a CollectionId of whatever was generated upon saving the PlaylistCollection.

**UPDATE:** This works but is clearly forced. How can I improve it?

// Inside of Playlist class:

```
[DataMember(Name = "collectionId")]
public Guid CollectionId
{
    get { return Collection.Id; }
    set { Collection.Id = value; }
}

public PlaylistCollection Collection { get; set; }
```

Doing this allows me to return my collectionId and NHibernate has figured out the mapping appropriately now... but still seems a bit forced to me.

Comment: you could try dropping the `inverse="true"` from your bags, since they are not bidirectional, at least as per the shown mappings.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. I was looking into the inverse property trying to decide if it was useful in my scenario. (I've removed them, but to no effect)

Comment: oh, do you really need to have the `CollectionId` property there be just a Guid? if you create a many to one mapping there, it should work (when you put back the `inverse="true"` on the bag in PLCollection). or is this an experiment? :)

Comment: I am going to serialize my User object and send it to the client after retrieving it from the database. I will have to deal with a circular reference if I change the property from CollectionId to a PlaylistCollection object.

Comment: i see. it's not as nice a solution as actually solving this mapping, but you might want to map the collection as a m-1, and expose an unmapped property which is the CollectionId and serialize it, and put a serialization ignore attribute on the collection. i'll be watching if anyone solves this :)

Comment: :) Yep that's what I am doing right now so I can continue working for now. Thanks for your advice.